# I am getting fatal error LNK1112 while compiling a Photoshop plugin through batch script

Tags: c++, batch-file, photoshop-sdk

I am trying to build an x64 Photoshop plugin through a batch script (there is no VS project) by modifying an example from sonictk's Photoshop C++ Recipes tutorials. Here is the script:

```
@echo off
setlocal

echo Build script started executing at %time% ...
set BuildType=%1
if "%BuildType%"=="" (set BuildType=release)

set PhotoshopSDKRoot=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ps_cpp_recipes-master\recipes\thirdparty\pluginsdk
set CnvtPiPLExePath="%PhotoshopSDKRoot%\samplecode\resources\Cnvtpipl.exe"
set PhotoshopPluginsDeployPath=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ps_cpp_recipes-master\recipes\Release

call "%vs2022installdir%\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64

set BuildDir=%~dp0msbuild
if not exist %BuildDir% mkdir %BuildDir%
pushd %BuildDir%

set ProjectName=my_filter

set EntryPoint=%~dp0src\%ProjectName%_main.cpp
set ResourcePiPL=%~dp0src\%ProjectName%_pipl.r
set ResourceRC=%BuildDir%\%ProjectName%_pipl.rc
set ResourceRES=%BuildDir%\%ProjectName%_pipl.res

set ThirdPartyDirPath=%~dp0..\thirdparty

set OutBin=%BuildDir%\%ProjectName%.8bf

set CommonLinkerFlags=/dll /incremental:no /machine:x64 /nologo /defaultlib:Kernel32.lib /defaultlib:User32.lib /defaultlib:Shell32.lib /nodefaultlib:LIBCMTD.lib /nodefaultlib:LIBCMT.lib "%ResourceRES%"
set DebugLinkerFlags=%CommonLinkerFlags% /opt:noref /debug /pdb:"%BuildDir%\%ProjectName%.pdb"
set ReleaseLinkerFlags=%CommonLinkerFlags% /opt:ref
set RelWithDebInfoLinkerFlags=%CommonLinkerFlags% /opt:ref /debug /pdb:"%BuildDir%\%ProjectName%.pdb"

set PSPreprocessorDefines=/DISOLATION_AWARE_ENABLED=1 /DWIN32=1 /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_WINDOWS /D_USRDLL /D_WINDLL /D_MBCS
set PSCompilerFlags=/EHsc
set CommonIncludePaths=/I "%ThirdPartyDirPath%" /I "%ThirdPartyDirPath%\psapi\common\includes" /I "%ThirdPartyDirPath%\psapi\common\resources" /I "%ThirdPartyDirPath%\psapi\common\sources" /I "%ThirdPartyDirPath%\psapi\photoshop" /I "%ThirdPartyDirPath%\psapi\pica_sp" /I "%ThirdPartyDirPath%\psapi\resources" /I "%ThirdPartyDirPath%\psapi\ai" /I "%BuildDir%"
set CommonCompilerFlags=/nologo /W3 /WX %CommonIncludePaths% /Zc:__cplusplus /arch:AVX2 %PSCompilerFlags% %PSPreprocessorDefines%
set CompilerFlagsDebug=%CommonCompilerFlags% /Od /Zi /D_DEBUG /MDd
set CompilerFlagsRelease=%CommonCompilerFlags% /Ox /DNDEBUG /MD
set CompilerFlagsRelWithDebInfo=%CommonCompilerFlags% /Ox /Zi /DNDEBUG /MD


if "%BuildType%"=="debug" (
    set BuildCommand=cl %CompilerFlagsDebug% "%EntryPoint%" /Fe:"%OutBin%" /link %DebugLinkerFlags%
    set BuildRRCommand=cl %CompilerFlagsDebug% /EP /DMSWindows=1 /Tc "%ResourcePiPL%"
) else if "%BuildType%"=="relwithdebinfo" (
    set BuildCommand=cl %CompilerFlagsRelWithDebInfo% "%EntryPoint%" /Fe:"%OutBin%" /link %RelWithDebInfoLinkerFlags%
    set BuildRRCommand=cl %CompilerFlagsRelWithDebInfo% /EP /DMSWindows=1 /Tc "%ResourcePiPL%"
) else (
    set BuildCommand=cl %CompilerFlagsRelease% "%EntryPoint%" /Fe:"%OutBin%" /link %ReleaseLinkerFlags%
    set BuildRRCommand=cl %CompilerFlagsRelease% /EP /DMSWindows=1 /Tc "%ResourcePiPL%"
)


echo.
echo Compiling resources (command follows below)...
set ResourceRR=%BuildDir%\%ProjectName%_pipl.rr

echo %BuildRRCommand%
%BuildRRCommand% > "%ResourceRR%"
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto error

echo.
echo Converting PiPL to  Windows resource file format...
echo %CnvtPiPLExePath% "%ResourceRR%" "%ResourceRC%"
%CnvtPiPLExePath% "%ResourceRR%" "%ResourceRC%"
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto error

echo.
echo Compiling Windows Resources...
rc /v /fo "%ResourceRES%" "%ResourceRC%"
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto error

echo.
echo Compiling source files for filter (command follows below)...
echo %BuildCommand%
echo.
echo Output from compilation:
%BuildCommand%
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto error

echo.
echo Deploying built binaries and symbols...
copy /Y "%OutBin%"  "%PhotoshopPluginsDeployPath%"
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto error

if "%BuildType%"=="debug" (
    copy /Y "%BuildDir%\%ProjectName%.pdb" "%PhotoshopPluginsDeployPath%"
    if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto error
)

if %errorlevel% == 0 goto success


:error
echo.
echo ***************************************
echo *      !!! An error occurred!!!       *
echo ***************************************
goto end


:success
echo.
echo ***************************************
echo *    Build completed successfully.    *
echo ***************************************
goto end


:end
echo.
echo Build script finished execution at %time%.
popd

endlocal

exit /b %errorlevel%
```

When running the batch file, I get the following error:
my_filter_main.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

When modifying machine:x64 to machine:x86 the plugin compiles as 32 bit, but in Photoshop although I can find it in the filters menu, it is unresponsive.

The internet and Stack Overflow have too broad explanations, and the only possible solution is by making the modification that I have already stated above.

For compilation, VS2022 vcvarsall.bat is called, but as sonictk states, I have to install VS2017. I have VS2017 Build Tools installed, tried to call vcvarsall.bat from there with the same results. Do I have to install VS2017 or just not to make assumptions by the fact that I have missed something which adds to this unsolved mystery?

Comment: Are you using an older 32-bit version of Photoshop?

Comment: @Ejay The 32-bit version is 2017. May I know why is this important?

Comment: If your Photoshop was 64-bit, and your plugin was 32-bit, the plugin may be unresponsive.

Comment: @Ejay The 64-bit version of Photoshop always throws error at startup when 32-bit plugin being accidentally placed in its plugins folder, therefore the plugin never shows up in the filters menu.

Comment: I have solved the problem with fatal error LNK1112 by installing VS2017 and successfully compiling the plugin through Native Tools Command Prompt for VS2017. I have question whether this is the only option and why this cannot be done with VS2022 just with using the 2017 Build Tools?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I suspect it may be due to one-or-more-of:  ODR, exact WinSDK version, or specific compiler dependencies plug-ins have on Photoshop's API.  Titus Winters (of Google) at PacificPlusPlus 2018 said, “Build everything from source at the same time with the same flags if possible.”  Third party plug-ins can't be built at the same time, but with care that can be built with a compatible environment, same compiler version, and same flags.  This (dare I call it) shortcoming with C++ is one of its accepted flaws.

Comment: @Eljay So, now this rises the next question, why some VS projects need the exact version to compile.

Comment: Different compiler flags can make two different object files not link compatible.  Imagine, for example, a -fshort-string-optimization flag, that if enabled changes the layout of `std::string`. Passing a string argument from one object file into another object file as a function's parameter will have different notions of what the internals of `std::string` look like.  It's a ODR violation, and results in **undefined behavior** (if you are lucky, it'll crash; if unlucky, it may appear to work).